# How to know if a url has parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I want to check if a url has parameters or it doesn't, so I know how to append the following parameters(with ? or &). In Javascript

Thanks in advance

Edit:
With this solution it works perfectly:

```
myURL.indexOf("?") > -1
```

Comment: Just split the Url by '?' and get length of split array if it is 1 then url doesnt have Parameter if more than one it have

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 11):

Split the string, and if the resulting array is greater than one and the second element isn't an empty string, then at least one parameter has been found.

```
var arr = url.split('?');
if (arr.length > 1 && arr[1] !== '') {
  console.log('params found');
}
```

Note this method will also work for the following edge-case:

```
http://myurl.net/?
```

You could also match the url against a regex:

```
if (url.match(/\?./)) {
  console.log(url.split('?'))
}
```

Comment: i had to change the condition if (url.length...) to if (arr.length...) and it worked fine for me

Answer (score 9):

Just go through the code snippet, First, get the complete URL and then check for `?` using `includes()` method.`includes()` can be used to find out substring exists or not and using `location` we can obtain full URL.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only (/path/example.html)
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL (https://example.com/path/example.html)
var origin   = window.location.origin;   // Returns base URL (https://example.com)
```

```js
let url = window.location.href;
if(url.includes('?')){
  console.log('Parameterised URL');
}else{
  console.log('No Parameters in URL');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
if (url.contains('?')) {} else {}
```

Comment: That's because ["`contains` is an experimental technology, part of the Harmony (ECMAScript 6) proposal."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains)

Comment: Now it is standard, but `url.includes(word);` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also.

```
var url = YourURL;
if(url.includes('?')) {} else {}
```

url.includes('?')  Will return true if ? exist in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the page and want to check if the page was called with parameters:

```
if (window.location.search) {
    console.log ("This page was called with paramters")
  } else {
    console.log ("No Parameters found")
  }
```